# How to we can set discount for specific Payment Card like Visa Or Master in Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I want add discount on specific Card or bank account ( If customer have Visa Card or have account in ABC Bank ) Then 25% off on all products when he'll place order.

How to we can do this ? There is any solution or extension is available for this issue ?

I am using M2.4.0.

Kind Regards,

Comment: I don't think it's possible the way you see it. Choosing a payment method (or a saved credit card let's say), is the last step at checkout. It's meant to be a place where the customer knows the price is set and won't change anymore. With that said, why do you want to do this in the first place...? Seems kinda weird to give a discount based on the credit card.

Comment: Well the idea is that since you tagged this with ***'payment-gateway'***, i am assuming that you have an integration with a payment processor and that the client is not adding the card data on your website, s/he is adding them on the payment gateway, so outside Magento. Basically you already have a submitted order by then and the payment amount is already added, so you can't change it.